# Limit of the integral over $[0,n]$ of $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}}$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I need some help calculating the following integral in measure theory:

$$\int_{0}^{n} (1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}}dx$$

So far what I tried was the following:

$$\int_{0}^{n} (1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}}dx$$

$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} (1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{x \leq n} \lambda (dx)$$

Then I calculated the limit of the term in the integral:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{x \leq n} = e^{x}e^{\frac{x}{2}} = e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$

And:

$$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx = 2$$

Now I wanted to use either the dominated convergence theorem or the monotone convergence theorem, but for either theorem I need either to show that $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ converges monotonically or that it's upper bounded by $e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$. I tried different approaches, but none of them helped me. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0\le x\le n$, then
$$
\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^n\le e^{-x}.
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\log\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)\le-\frac{x}{n},
$$
which follows fron the inequality $\log(1-x)\le-x$ if $0\le x<1$.